# DAX Calc. Column with true/false entry only in latest instance per category

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would need the fourth, calculated column, to the below ex. table. Category is 'case' and entry is in the latest 'date' record per category, based on the 'result' from the latest 'date'

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final result = 

 VAR tbl = CALCULATETABLE('Table', ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[case]))
 VAR maxDate = MAXX(tbl, 'Table'[date])

 RETURN 
 IF('Table'[date] = maxDate,
    CONCATENATEX( 
        FILTER(tbl,  'Table'[date] = maxDate), 'Table'[result]
    ), ""
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks but this works only if text values in the 'final result'. For the true/false all the cells are filled in. Would you propose something for true/false and blank values?

Comment: I don't understand sorry. This code works with your sample data. If you have different sample data, then please update your question or post a new question.

Comment: No, data is fine. Maybe I expressed it badly. I mean that once I format the output column from text to true/false values blanks will be filled with 'false'

Comment: I see. Let me take a look a bit later for you.

Comment: I have updated my code for you.